# High & Low of previous periods indicator, how to plot on chart just the last period?

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I have an indicator that plot on chart, using lines, previous periods High and Low, it works properly for daily and weekly periods.
[Screenshot of my working indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQenZ.png)

On the chart it shows every previous period while I need only the last period, for example just last week or just last day.

```
    study(title="Previous Day High and Low + OPENS", shorttitle="HLO", overlay=true)

D_High = security(tickerid, 'D', high[1]) 
D_Low = security(tickerid, 'D', low[1]) 
D_Close =  security(tickerid, 'D', close[1]) 
D_Open =  security(tickerid, 'D', open[1]) 
W_High =  security(tickerid, 'W', high[1]) 
W_Low =  security(tickerid, 'W', low[1])


plot(isintraday ? D_High : na, title="Daily High",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 
plot(isintraday ? D_Low : na, title="Daily Low",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 

plot(isintraday ? W_High : na, title="Weekly High",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 
plot(isintraday ? W_Low : na, title="Weekly Low",style=line, color=black,linewidth=1) 

openPriceD = security(tickerid, 'D', open)

openPriceW = security(tickerid, 'W', open)

openPriceM = security(tickerid, 'M', open)

plot(openPriceD ? openPriceD : na, title="Daily Open", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=purple)

plot(openPriceW ? openPriceW : na, title="Weekly Open", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=green)

plot(openPriceM ? openPriceM : na, title="Monthly Open", style=circles, linewidth=2, color=red)
```

I tried to add the "show_last=" function to the plot string but it doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: I think this question will help you achieve what you need [How to plot a horizontal line based off a specific closing candle and timeframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532646/how-to-plot-a-horizontal-line-based-off-a-specific-closing-candle-and-timeframe)

Comment: Thanks for the help Bjorn. Unfortunately, since my knowledge as programmer is very poor I can't get much of that. I hoped to get a simplier answer on how to update the code of my indicator.

Answer (score -1):

This will plot the high of the previous day on today's candles.

```
//@version=4
study("Q62089672", overlay=true)

D_High = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high)

isSaturday = dayofweek(timenow) == dayofweek.saturday
isSunday   = dayofweek(timenow) == dayofweek.sunday
offSetDays = isSaturday ? 1 : isSunday ? 2 : 0

showFromDate = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow)-offSetDays, 0, 0, 0)

canShow = timeframe.isintraday and time >= showFromDate

plot(canShow ? D_High[1] : na, title="Previous day high", style=plot.style_line, color=color.yellow, linewidth=1)
```

Which yields this output

[image: Previous day high]

The times at which the lines start may be off because of time zone differences.
Each ticker has its own time zone in which it trades.

[image: Symbol timezone]

You can also specify a timezone in the [`security()` function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_security).

For more details and examples, see

- [A closer look at TradingView's syminfo.timezone variable](https://kodify.net/tradingview/info/syminfo-timezone/)
- [How to set a TradingView chart to the instrument's ‘Exchange’ time
  zone?](https://kodify.net/tradingview/platform/exchange-time-zone/).

Comment: That's perfect. Copying and paste your code my indicator shows the line from 7.00 AM and not from the beginning of the day.
Moreover, using this code, I modified the string to also show the weekly high and low but it doesn't seem to work.
I keep on trying doing experiment. 
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide more info on why that is, and where you can get more information on how to mitigate for time zone differences.

Comment: On the link "my working indicator" you can see that it already works properly and I just need to show the last day high and low instead of plotting it on the whole chart. I'm sorry I'm not allowed yet to post full images due to my newbie status :)

Comment: You can do that with the code I provided. You'll just have to modify it to account for timezone differences. When you need help from the community with a coding problem, it's generally better to provide the entire script.

Comment: I'm sure about it, but since unfortunately my skills are poor I'm not quite able to do that, the script I use is copied from an existent one and then slightly modified by myself. I'm not able to create a new blank code by myself so I hoped to modify my indicator and let it work. I just updated the post with the whole script. Thanks again Bjorn

Comment: Could you please include the @version line in your script? That's important. And also the link to the original script. That could help too.

Comment: Sure. If you mean the line where the version number is, strangely I can't see it on this script.  I copied all the code that I'm able to visualize, where can I find it? I'm sorry but I don't remember what the original script was, It was months ago and on tradingview there are many similar scripts to this